# Azure self-hosted agent kubernetes task fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am using Azure self-hosted agents using VMSS, when running `Kubernetes@1` task on the agent it returns this error `couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://<aks>.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp: lookup <aks>.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host`. AKS is not private and this setup was working when running on agents provided by Azure. The task I am trying to run looks like this:

```yaml
steps:
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    displayName: "Rollout <deployment-name>"
    inputs:
      connectionType: "Kubernetes Service Connection"
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: <serviceEndpoint>
      namespace: <namespace>
      command: "rollout"
      arguments: "restart deployment <deployment-name>"
```

Agent is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Using `AzureCLI@2` task which obtains credentials and executes `kubectl` command does work, but it is not optimal solution and I would like to use `Kubernetes@1` task. This is example of working `AzureCLI@2` task:

```yaml
steps:
 - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group> --name <aks-name>
        kubectl rollout -n <namespace> restart deployment <deployment-name>
```

EDIT:

- I am using Service Account and not kube config file.
- I have a custom image which comes with preinstalled kubectl command.

Answer (score 1):

**I have followed the steps given below and it worked for me.**

**Step 1:** Create VMSS and install a **kubectl** by connecting to the VMSS.
Run the below commands on VMSS to install kubectl.

```
$curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
$sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

[image]

Refer to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#install-using-other-package-management) for more information on installing kubectl.

**Step 2:** Add VMSS as self-hosted agent in ADO organization.

[image]

**Step 3:** I have created a **service connection** using **kube config** file.

[image]

**Step 4:** Run the pipeline by choosing the pool created in **step 2** and verify the result.
[image]

```
  - task: Kubernetes@1
    displayName: "Rollout nginx-deployment"
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
      kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'svc-aks'
      namespace: 'default'
      command: 'rollout'
      arguments: 'restart deployment nginx-deployment'
      secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
      containerRegistryType: 'Container Registry'
```

[image]

Comment: I missed one bit of information in my original post. I am using Service Account. I am also using a custom image for VMSS, which does have kubectl installed. I'll update the original question with missing information.